# logstash issue on starting (in kubernetes pod)

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

i start a logstash service in a container, via a kubernetes Pod,
and i volontary changed the config to see the behaviour.
Now, the config file of the service is not

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
 }
```

but

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["elasticsearch1:9200"]
 }
```

Then, when i start the container, the logs are :

```
[2023-01-13T14:26:49,474][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch1:9200/]}}
[2023-01-13T14:26:50,076][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch1:9200/"}
```

so refer to elasticsearch1
and then suddenly refer to elasticsearch

```
[2023-01-13T14:27:01,405][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
```

why ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to any elasticsearch instances defined in plugins, logstash will try to connect to the elasticsearch instance defined by xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts in logstash.yml in order to check what licence you are running with.